# Citation Style Language (CSL)

Tags: bibliographies, citing, csl

How can I use [Citation Style Language](http://citationstyles.org/downloads/specification.html)(CSL) in LaTeX Bibliography? It seems fantastic, there is 2,803 Citation Style right now in [Zotero Style Repository](http://www.zotero.org/styles).

> The Citation Style Language (CSL) is an  XML format for describing the
>   formatting of in-text citations, notes and bibliographies. CSL offers:
>
> - An open format that may be used by any application
> - The ability to write compact and robust styles
> - Extensive support for style requirements
> - Automatic style localization
> - Easy distribution and updating of styles
> - A fast growing library with thousands of freely available styles

Comment: never heard of such a thing, but some xsl (to generate a native language such as bibtex) wouldn't (surely) be difficult.  never heard of anyone doing such a thing, though.

Comment: maybe this interview is of interest for you: http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2012/08/textalk-an-interview-with-plk/

Comment: Related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261023/is-it-possible-to-convert-a-citation-style-language-csl-style-file-to-a-bibtex

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is in fact a tool to use CSL when compiling LaTeX documents. [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) accepts a `--csl=<csl file>` argument, and it will use the supplied CSL style to format your bibliography.

For example:

```
pandoc --bibliography=refs.bib --csl=mystyle.csl -o out.pdf doc.tex
```

Will happily generate `out.pdf` file via LaTeX using the bibtex file `refs.bib` and CSL file `mystyle.csl`, from source `doc.tex`, which presumably has a `\thebibliography` or some citations in there somewhere.

Comment: This is a great idea for many use cases. However, Pandoc uses only a subset of LaTeX and when converting from raw TeX, the internal document model doesn't even support some basic LaTeX environments like \includegraphics.

Comment: @Arthur sorry, but that's incorrect. Pandoc passes the LaTeX through either XeTeX or PDFTeX, and supports whatever they do as long as your output is in a format that doesn't require additional transformation by Pandoc.

I've used \includegraphics before via Pandoc, since the Pandoc markdown format doesn't support image transforms.

Comment: I should have been more specific. [See this issue on the Pandoc GitHub](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/317); specifying width/height is not supported which, to my mind, means `\includegraphics` is not fully supported.

Comment: @Arthur, I believe that issue only applies to converting _from_ latex to _non-latex_ output formats. So if `.pdf` or `.tex` is your output format, then those specifications are respected.

Comment: @Arthur You can simply use latex `includegraphics` in your source and pandoc will include that in the tex intermediate step, then you can choose to compile pdf or whatever, no issue.

Answer (score 21):

In one word: no.

Bruce D'Arcus, the original creator of CSL, has repeatedly said that he would like to see an implementation of CSL for LaTeX (to be more precise: he often talked about LuaLaTeX) and that such a thing wouldn't be too difficult to achieve in theory (see [this](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2008-11/msg00563.html) and the following posts for example), but so far, no one has been interested in doing it (the post I linked to dates back to 2008!).

In my opinion, CSL for LaTeX would be extremely useful. CSL is getting more and more traction (there are about half a dozen of implementations ATM), and although it's not quite as powerful as `biblatex` (but what is?), it's very versatile, and, most important, truly system-agnostic.

It would be the first solution to offer bibliography styles which work equally for a LaTeX and a variety of word processors and is really able to deal with complex styles.

Comment: What you mean from: "although it's not quite as powerful as biblatex ...", I think they are not comparable, indeed BibLaTeX may use CSL files to style its output.

Comment: I mean, among other things, that `biblatex` has a more exhaustive data model, allows (in combination with `biber`) for more complex sorting and offers more fine-grained typographic control. And no, CSL files are completely useless for `biblatex`.

Comment: "...CSL files are completely useless for `biblatex.` " ????????

Comment: Yes, they are. CSL files need a CSL processor which `biblatex` is not, which, as I wrote in my answer, doesn't exist (yet) for `LaTeX`.

Comment: @Simifilm `biber` would be such a processor. Given its active development, it'd be a prime candidate for use.

Comment: Turning `biber` into a CSL processor would mean rewriting it from scratch. `biker` was designed for handling `biblatex's` styles, there's nothing in the program which helps you with CSL at the moment. Adding a CSL processor to it, doesn't really make a lot of sense anyway, you could just write a new program.

Answer (score 15):

Edit:

[citeproc-lua](https://github.com/zepinglee/citeproc-lua) now contains it's own LaTeX package, it added support for BibTeX files and it uses the normal LaTeX citation commands. It is available on [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/citation-style-language), so you can install it using `tlmgr`.

See also the [instructions on how to run the example](https://github.com/zepinglee/citeproc-lua/tree/main/example):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{citation-style-language}
\cslsetup{style = apa}
\addbibresource{example.bib}

\begin{document}

Foo \cite{ITEM-1} bar \cite{ITEM-1, ITEM-2} baz.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

Original answer:

There is now a full [Lua version of Citeproc](https://github.com/zepinglee/citeproc-lua). It doesn't contain TeX interface yet, but simple package for LuaLaTeX that uses it can look like this `citeproc.sty`:

```
\ProvidesPackage{citeproc}
\RequirePackage{luacode}

% Basic initialization of Citeproc.lua

\begin{luacode*}
require("lualibs")

-- global object for functions defined in this 
CSL = {}

local dom = require("luaxml-domobject")
local formats = require("citeproc.citeproc-formats")

local CiteProc = require("citeproc")


local function read_file(path)
    local file = io.open(path, "r")
    if not file then return nil end
    local content = file:read("*a")
    file:close()
    return content
end


function CSL.load_style(filename)
  CSL.style = read_file(filename)
end

function CSL.load_json(filename)
  CSL.bib = CSL.bib or {}
  local items = utilities.json.tolua(read_file(filename)) 
  if not items then
    return nil, "JSON file cannot be loaded: " .. filename
  end
  for _, item in ipairs(items) do
    CSL.bib[item["id"]] = item
  end
end

function CSL.load_lang(lang)
  CSL.lang= lang
end

function CSL.load_style(style)
  CSL.style = read_file(style)
end

function make_citeproc_sys(bib)
  local bib = bib
  local citeproc_sys = {
    retrieveLocale = function (self, lang)
      local locale_name_format = CSL.locale_name_format or "locales-%s.xml"
      local filename = string.format(locale_name_format, lang)
      local content = read_file(filename)
      if content then
        return dom.parse(content)
      else
        return nil
      end
    end,
    retrieveItem = function (self, id)
      return bib[id]
    end
  }
  return citeproc_sys
end

function CSL.init()
  CSL.bib = CSL.bib or {}
  local citeproc_sys = make_citeproc_sys(CSL.bib)
  CSL.citeproc = CiteProc:new(citeproc_sys, CSL.style)
  CSL.citeproc.formatter = formats.latex
end

function CSL.cite(citation)
  local cite_items = {}
  for item in string.gmatch(citation, "([^,]+)") do 
    cite_items[#cite_items+1] = {id = item}
  end
  local result = CSL.citeproc:makeCitationCluster(cite_items)
  tex.print(result)
end

function CSL.bibliography()
    local params, result = CSL.citeproc:makeBibliography()
    tex.print("\\begin{thebibliography}{}")
    for _,bibitem in pairs(result) do
      bibitem = bibitem:gsub("bibitem%[.-%]","bibitem")
      tex.print(bibitem)
    end
    tex.print("\\end{thebibliography}")
end


\end{luacode*}

\newcommand\cslstyle[1]{%
  \luaexec{CSL.load_style("#1")}
}

\newcommand\csljson[1]{%
  \luaexec{CSL.load_json("#1")}
}

\newcommand\cslinit{%
\luaexec{CSL.init()}
}

\newcommand\cslcite[1]{%
  \luaexec{CSL.cite("\luaescapestring{#1}")}
}

\newcommand\cslbibliography{\luaexec{CSL.bibliography()}}

% initialize citeproc
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \cslinit%
}


\endinput
```

It doesn't support BibTeX files, it needs JSON at the moment. To run the following example, download `bib.json`, `simple.csl`, and `locales-en-US.xml` from the [Citeproc-lua example directory](https://github.com/zepinglee/citeproc-lua/tree/main/example).

The `sample.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{citeproc}
\cslstyle{simple.csl}
\csljson{bib.json}
\begin{document}
hello world \cslcite{ITEM-1,ITEM-2}

\cslbibliography
\end{document}
```

You can compile it using LuaLaTeX. This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Wow! This is soo amazing

Comment: @DG' the Citeproc-lua now contains its own LaTeX package, it is much better than my version. It also supports BibTeX files now. The development is really fast, I think it will be usable soon.

Comment: @michal.h21 That's pretty cool!

Comment: @michal.h21 - I hope so. This is really great news.

Comment: @michal.h21 Is the LaTeX package supposed to work with any style other than `plain.csl` which is provided? I tried several other styles which validate correctly, but they only produced error messages and gibberish.

Comment: @Simifilm I think it should support most styles, but it is still in active development and doesn't support 100 % of CSL features. I think it would be best to post a new issue to the Github Repo.

Comment: Could anyone fill me in on the process of this one here? I have an Uni-intern CSL stlye and want to make it run in LaTex on BibTex...

Comment: @poebelchen - [citation-style-language](https://ctan.org/pkg/citation-style-language) replaces BibTEX. How to run it depends on your latex engine, which is described in the package docs. If you have any issues, then please ask a new questions

Answer (score 11):

I've created a Guile Scheme program that can parse a .aux file and produce a .bbl via the Juris-M or Zotero reference manager along with the Better BibTeX for Zotero plugin, modified to provide a bbl format output from its "schomd" interface.

See: https://github.com/KarlHegbloom/zotero-texmacs-integration

It is incomplete. The script in the top directory will run and produce a .bbl as long as you have Juris-M or Zotero and the version of Better BibTeX for Zotero installed that supports it. I've used it to produce a bibliography in Bluebook format (US legal writing). Eventually I will have support in TeXmacs similar to what's in the OpenOffice pluginfor Zotero, so it will handle formatting the in-document citations as well as the bibliography.

Comment: This looks very interesting. Will it handle citations too? (As you know surely , the rules for creating and referencing shorthands for subsequent in legal articles can be cumbersome to do correctly *and* automatically.)

Comment: Not quite yet. I'm too busy preparing documents right now to stop and finish. After I'm done with this lawsuit and I have a little more time for it I plan to finish the support. I've decided that what I will do is clone the Open Office plug-in that's written in JavaScript inside Juris-M and Zotero, modify it to talk to code that I will write inside of texmacs.

Answer (score 1):

If you write your LaTeX document through RMarkdown, you have the ability to set a csl parameter in the header of your file (ie the YAML header). It's conveniently straight-forward, here's an example YAML header for an RMarkdown:

```
---
output: 
  pdf_document
title: 'Title of document'
author:
  name: "My Name"
bibliography: references.bib
csl: biblio_style.csl

---

Text [@reference].
# References
```

Comment: Note that RMarkdown uses Pandoc to compile, so it is basically the same as [the accepted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/146123/) above but then with the command line arguments given as a YAML header instead.

Comment: @Marijn The pandoc command in the accepted answer messed up my PDF formatting. RMarkdown took care of all my issues so there's definitely utility in using it