# Is it possible to convert a citation style language (csl) style file to a bibtext (bst) style file?

Tags: bibtex, conversion, csl

I am in a bind, trying to wrap up my thesis in two weeks time.
My university requires me to use their citation style, which they only provide for endnote or zotero.

Since all my citations are in bibtex (which I know, and I have no time to experiment with other bibliographic formats or programs, trying to make them collaborate with latex) I wonder if there is any possible way to convert a citation style language (csl) style file into a bst file that I can use. That would make life so much easier.

I have googled and searched the forums that I know of, but all answers I have seen are discouraging. They are however not up to date. If someone knows of a procedure to accomplish csl->bst style file I would be highly indebted.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69267

Comment: Thankyou, I read that post. Biblatex with biber sounds really intresting. Pandoc is however not working out for me.  I have tried to find easy answers on how to use biblatex with biber, but it seems like reading the manual is the only way here. I think I will try that if I can not convert the csl to bst, allthough I don't really have the time available.  Does pdflatex and biber take a plain bibfile without complaints?

Comment: @niclasericsson Yes, `biber` and `biblatex` deal with `.bib` files without any problem. The idea that a university would determine citation style (as opposed to your field of research) is kind of mind boggling. But there are plenty of `biblatex` styles already in use and I would be very surprised if you couldn't implement your university's style without too much effort.

Comment: @AlanMunn. Thankyou, I will give biber a go then. I agree it is mind boggling that they don't use a common citation style. I fully understand that they want consistent styles in all the thesis that are produced here, but can not for the life of me understand why they went and bothered to make their own style. But what is more annoying is their complete support for anything that integrate with Wurd and vinduuus, and no support whatsoever for opensource and latex. Now I have to go and learn a little about biblatex and biber compiling.

Comment: @niclasericsson Basically using `biblatex` and `biber` is almost identical to using `bibtex` and e.g. `natbib`. So really what you need is a good specification of your university's style. Is it published anywhere? Then perhaps we could give you some recommendations on the best `biblatex` style to start with.

Comment: See [What to do to switch to biblatex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091) to get you started.

Comment: @AlanMunn yes it is published on the [Zotero style repository](https://www.zotero.org/styles) under [Acta Universitatis Agriculturae Sueciae](https://www.zotero.org/styles/acta-universitatis-agriculturae-sueciae).  Its a csl file. Doesn't that work directly with biber?

Comment: Thanks for the link to help with the switch to biblatex :)

Comment: @AlanMunn I probably missunderstood specification. You mean written instructions I suppose. No, they don't have those published. I am trying hard to get them so I at least can make my own style file. I tried to switch to biblatex following the instructions in [your suggested question](tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/), using only `[backend=biber,natbib=true]` as options to biblatex and no options for `\printbibliography`. It gets the inline citings right, but does not print the bibliography list. What might I be doing wrong
(I am using texmaker)

Comment: I got biblatex working now. I forgot to change the bib(la)tex engine to biber in texmaker settings. Now I just need to figure out how to make biber take a csl style file and feed to it to biblatex, or learn how to format the citestyle and bibliographystyle. Authoryear default is not what I need.

Comment: @niclasericsson This doesn't look like it would be too hard to do, though.  [This site](http://editor.citationstyles.org/styleInfo/?styleId=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.zotero.org%2Fstyles%2Facta-universitatis-agriculturae-sueciae) seems like a good way to see all the possible entry formats.

Comment: @AlanMunn Yes, but it is kind of hard to tell some of those entries apart. I have asked my librarians to send me their style specifications. They must have one. If they cannot, I guess I will have to interpret that list. Thanks for your help anyway. I got the hang of biblatex now.  Both the inline citings and bibliography is looking okay

Comment: There is a way to use CSL files in LaTeX now. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/618815/35864

Answer (score -1):

You can use BibTeX with Zotero; if I understood what you mean, this should solve the problem:
[BibTex and LaTex: Export from Zotero](https://libguides.usask.ca/c.php?g=218034&p=1446406)

[Using Zotero with LaTeX and BibTeX FAQ](https://libguides.princeton.edu/c.php?g=148292&p=991756)