# Use .csl or .ccs for bibtex

Tags: bibtex, csl

I am wanting to write my thesis with LaTeX. My problem is, that my university demands a certain citation style, which they provide as a `.csl` or `.ccs` file.

Is there some way to use that in LaTeX / BibTeX?

Comment: Welcome! Can you check your question? I'm assuming there was a typo in the subject and you meant `.ccs`. If not, there was presumably one in the body and you meant `.css`. (But it seems odd for a university to provide a style as CSS.) What are `.csl` and/or `.ccs`?

Comment: I've never heard of either of these formats: can you link to one?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citation_Style_Language perhaps? In that case, 'no, not directly', but it is just a description of the format, which can be reproduced.

Comment: @JosephWright `.ccs` is Citavi? Maybe?

Comment: [Citavi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citavi)

Comment: No. See [Is it possible to convert a citation style language (csl) style file to a bibtext (bst) style file?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261023/is-it-possible-to-convert-a-citation-style-language-csl-style-file-to-a-bibtex)

Comment: 50% duplicate of [Citation Style Language (CSL)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69267/citation-style-language-csl).

Comment: thanks a lot for your help!

so the style the provide is this one: (.csl) https://www.zotero.org/styles/universitatsmedizin-gottingen
and I guess .csl is what zotero uses?

the .ccs (citavi) I found here:
https://support.citavi.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=98&t=5469

so I've tried to look into the .bst I have always used for my other work, but really have not a bit of clue how to adapt it to the uni's requirements.... :(
is there some easy way to create an according .bst?

Answer (score 2):

[Pandoc](http://pandoc.org)  can *read* and *write* `tex`files and use `csl` files to generate citations and bibliography. So, you can try something like:
`pandoc File.tex --bibliography=Bibfile.bib --csl=Mycsl.csl -o FileWithBib.tex` and then latex `FileWithBib.tex`.

If you use this, you must write the preamble in `FileWithBib.tex`

Comment: okay thanks, I'll try that. But I'm wondering, when I use pandoc, will I still ave the bibliography compiled with pandoc in my output pdf that I create with latex? Or do I use pandoc to compile the .tex in the first place?
Sorry, but I don't really understand what exactly pandoc is doing...

Comment: Oh, reading your answer again, I guess I compile the FileWithBib.text in latex and that will have the bibliography of interest included, right?
pandoc confuses me ;)

Comment: Yes with this strategy `pandoc` is use just for formating the bibliography. In the `FileWithBib.tex` we have the citing formated as define in the `cls` and the bibliography at the end of the file. You must rework a little `FileWithBib.tex` (`pandoc` create links in the bibliography).