# Converting a csl file to a bst file

Tags: citing, natbib, custom-bib, mendeley

My university asks citation in a specific format which they have published as a csl file over Mendeley. However, since I'm using LaTex for my report I will need a bst file for the same. Does anyone know a workaround with this?

Comment: Pandoc can use CSL. Take a look here: pandoc.org

Comment: Maybe you can make the .bst  style in bibtex with `latex makebst` (+ answer to **a lot** of questions) but probably will be better mimic that style  using biblatex. BTW, this is an exact duplicate of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261023/is-it-possible-to-convert-a-citation-style-language-csl-style-file-to-a-bibtex),  but "There can be only one".

Answer (score 1):

You can use the csl file directly in latex. Replace **name of your csl file** and **name of your reference file** in the example below

```
% !TeX program = lualatex  % This magic comment must be the first line of your %code
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=name of your csl file,bib-item-sep=0.5cm]{citation-style-language}
\addbibresource{name of your reference file.bib}
\begin{document}

\printbibliography % This print your references

\end{document}
```

Comment: @teddy-van-jerry.org Thanks for formatting my answer.