# Zotero citation styles in LaTeX

Tags: biblatex, zotero

I've recently started to use Zotero as reference manager. However, the bibliography in the compiled PDF document is formatted differently from what I see in the citation style manager of Zotero. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass [12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setmainfont{Simoncini Garamond Std}
\usepackage{microtype}
\microtypesetup{final}

\usepackage[autostyle,italian=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[bibstyle=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}

\textcite{motolinia2020, blumenau2020, abdul-razzak2020, ceron2019}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

When Zotero is used to export `.bib` files for use with bibliography solutions from the LaTeX world (classical BibTeX or `biblatex`), then Zotero does not decide the citation or bibliography style at all. (Certain parts of the `.bib` output can indirectly influence the output, but ultimately and primarily the decisions are up to the bibliography and citation styles you select with BibTeX or `biblatex`). Zotero only helps provide the entry data. In particular any citation or bibliography previews on the Zotero side will have no direct influence on the style selected in your document and may in fact have no connection to what you are going to see whatsoever.

If you want to use `biblatex`, then you have to rely on what you see in your document. You haven't told us what output you'd like to see, but the code in the question mixes an autor-year bibliography (`bibstyle=authoryear,`) with numeric citations (the [effectively] pre-set `citestyle=numeric,`), which is a bit ... unusual. A slightly saner setup might be a complete author-year style like

```
\documentclass [12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setmainfont{Simoncini Garamond Std}
\usepackage{microtype}
\microtypesetup{final}

\usepackage[autostyle,italian=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}

\textcite{motolinia2020, blumenau2020, abdul-razzak2020, ceron2019}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I think Zotero uses CSL files for previews and formatting in other word processors. So if you want to get the same output as in the Zotero preview, you have to make use of those files. As far as I am aware there is no way to use CSL files natively with LaTeX, the only way I know is via pandoc. (See [Citation Style Language (CSL)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69267/35864.)) Then, however, you would neither be using BibTeX nor `biblatex` on the LaTeX side.

Comment: Thank you, you've been most helpful

Comment: I think this post may help you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69267/citation-style-language-csl