# What should I do to modify the in-text parenthetical citation style in apalike.bst?

Tags: apa-style, apa7, bst

I edit the article on Overleaf and tried to cite articles in the text with parenthetical citation style according to APA 7th. I found `apalike.bst` but it seems not correspondent to the citation style of APA 7th. For example:

```
It is argued that back vowels are fronted after the breathy-voiced plosives. \citep{SyfarGare}
```

The output would be

> It is argued that back vowels are fronted after the breathy-voiced plosives.
> (Seyfarth and Garellek, 2018)

Instead of "and", the conjunction of two authors should be connected by an ampersand ('&') in parenthetical citations according to APA 7th.

> It is argued that back vowels are fronted after the breathy-voiced plosives. (Seyfarth & Garellek, 2018)

In narrative citation, however, the conjunction should be the word "and".

```
\cite{SyfarGare} indicated that back vowels are fronted after the breathy-voiced plosives.
```

The output would be

> Seyfarth and Garellek (2018) indicated that back vowels are fronted after the breathy-voiced plosives.

I knew that it is possible to modify style in `bst file` but I wonder which function I should work on to change the conjunction to match APA 7th? Or is there better choice for `bst file` about APA 7th?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. If you need to adhere to the formatting guidelines of a recent edition of the "APA Manual", you should absolutely not be employing the decades-old `apalike` bibliography style. At present, there is no BibTeX-based implementation of the APA7 formatting guidelines/requirements. If you can live with the APA6 guidelines, the `apacite` package and bib style should be useful to you. If APA7 is essential, you'll need to switch to the `biblatex` package (with the package option `style=apa`) and biber.

Answer (score 1):

`apalike` is part of BibTeX base style bundle and has largely been unchanged since the late 1980s.

I'm not even sure if the style implemented APA guidelines at the time it was released. (After all it is called `apalike`, so we can really only expect it is "like APA" and not real APA.) But I can assure you that at the moment `apalike` definitely does not implement current APA style requirements.

The APA style requirements are quite involved. So if you need real APA style, you need to use more involved styles.

- For APA6 you have a choice between

  - the BibTeX-based `apacite` and
  - `biblatex-apa6` (i.e. `\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa6,]{biblatex}`)
- For APA7 there is only

  - `biblatex-apa` (i.e. `\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa,]{biblatex}`). Note that you need at least v9.0 (2019-11-23), older releases implemented APA6. Some earlier versions of the v9.x range had small bugs, so try to get the newest version available.

I should note that CSL styles can now be used with LaTeX (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/618815/35864) and an APA CSL is available (https://github.com/citation-style-language/styles/blob/master/apa.csl), but at the moment the LaTeX implementation does not seem to support different citation commands (e.g. for narrative vs parenthetical citations). See https://github.com/zepinglee/citeproc-lua/issues/17.

See also [Is there a way to apply Apa 7th references and citation style in latex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/527497/35864) (with an example document using `biblatex-apa`).

Have a look at [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864), [biblatex in a nutshell (for beginners)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864) if you need help navigating your way around BibTeX, `biblatex`, Biber, ....

Answer (score 0):

I recommend making some changes to the existing `apalike.bst`. But I don't know what the specific code in your `apalike.bst` is. Hope my answer can be helpful to someone.

*First*, in order to modify the in-text citation to (Seyfarth & Garellek, 2018), we might make the following changes.

The original code is

```
FUNCTION {format.lab.names}
{ 's :=
  "" 't :=
  s #1 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
  s num.names$ duplicate$
  #2 >
    { pop$
      " " * bbl.etal *
    }
    { #2 <
        'skip$
        { s #2 "{ff }{vv }{ll}{ jj}" format.name$ "others" =
            {
              " " * bbl.etal *
            }
            { bbl.and space.word * s #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
              * }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

Modify to:

```
FUNCTION {format.lab.names}
{ 's :=
  "" 't :=
  s #1 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
  s num.names$ duplicate$
  #2 >
    { pop$
      " " * bbl.etal *
    }
    { #2 <
        'skip$
        { s #2 "{ff }{vv }{ll}{ jj}" format.name$ "others" =
            {
              " " * bbl.etal *
            }
            { "\&" space.word * s #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
              * }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

Namely, change "bbl.and" to "\&" on line 16.

*Second*, in narrative citation, we can input:

```
Seyfarth and Garellek \citeyearpar{SyfarGare} indicated that back vowels are fronted after the breathy-voiced plosives.
```

The output would be:

Seyfarth and Garellek (2018) indicated that back vowels are fronted after the breathy-voiced plosives.