# How can I use CSL with pdflatex?

Tags: pdftex, csl

A [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69267/citation-style-language-csl) asked about how to use a CSL-defined bibliography style with LaTeX. The accepted answer gave the following use:

```
pandoc --bibliography=refs.bib --csl=mystyle.csl -o out.pdf doc.tex
```

However, when I used pandoc to convert my tex file to a pdf, it messed up the formatting and recommended I use pdflatex instead. So I did use pdflatex and it preserves the correct formatting of my .tex file. However, I do not see any pdflatex options for including a citation style like one defined in a CSL file. So, my question is, if I want to convert my tex file to a PDF using pdflatex, is there any way to compile such that my citations are formatted by a specified .csl file?

Comment: I know you have seen https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69267/citation-style-language-csl have you actually tried the packages it mentions, like `citeproc-lua` ?

Comment: I tried the \usepackage{citation-style-language} but I was not able to get it working. I had placed a .csl in a project in overleaf but the style=name.csl parameter didnt seem to recognize my csl file

Comment: However, I was able to get properly formatted pdfs with csl-specified citation styles using RMarkdown. So I might self-answer, but im still open to other methods

Comment: When used with pdftex, `citeproc-lua` requires manually running `citeproc-lua foo.aux` in the command line. However Overleaf can only run `latexmk` which currently cannot call citeproc-lua.