# How to find a style that displays an unusual text field?

Tags: bibliographies, pandoc, csl

**I have moved this question over to SO, because it involves Pandoc, citeproc, and CSL, but not biblatex.  Please answer [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76468231/find-a-csl-style-that-shows-a-particular-field) if you can.**

I have a biblatex file produced automatically by R that contains citations for R packages.  The document will be processed by Pandoc using the `--citeproc` option; that package uses CSL styles.  For example, it contains

```
@Manual{R-tables,
  title = {tables: Formula-Driven Table Generation},
  author = {Duncan Murdoch},
  note = {R package version 0.9.21},
  url = {https://dmurdoch.github.io/tables/},
  year = {2023},
}
```

I would like the reference list using this to include everything, but so far all the CSL styles I've tried skip the `note`, so I get something like

> Murdoch, Duncan. 2023. *Tables: Formula-Driven Table Generation.* https://dmurdoch.github.io/tables/.

when I would like it to look like

> Murdoch, Duncan. 2023. *Tables: Formula-Driven Table Generation.* R package version 0.9.21.  https://dmurdoch.github.io/tables/.

Can anyone suggest how to find CSL styles that display the `note` like that?

EDITED to add:

I've found a solution that's good enough as a workaround, but I'm still interested in the answer to my question. If I change `note` to `edition` the display looks okay to me. But how would I search for styles showing a particular field next time this comes up?

EDITED again:

A comment asked for a self-contained demonstration.  I've attached one below.  The original was written in R Markdown, but I've simplified it to plain Markdown.  Put the text below into `test.md` and the .bib entry above into `packages.bib`, then run

```
pandoc test.md --output test.html --citeproc
```

and you should get output that looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

```
---
bibliography: packages.bib
---

## The citation

This is a citation of the *tables* package [@R-tables].

## References
```

I think this probably doesn't actually involve `biblatex`, but my understanding is that Pandoc is supposed to emulate it.  So maybe I'm asking this question in the wrong place, or with the wrong tags.  But anyway, any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What styles have you tried? Are you using biblatex or bibtex?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: I've tried `apa` and `american-statistical-association` and a few others.  I'm using Pandoc to emulate `biber/biblatex`.

Comment: If I load the `biblatex` package with the option `style=american-statistical-association`, I get the following error message: `Package biblatex Info: ... file 'american-statistical-association.dbx' not found.`.

Comment: @Mico I think these are CSL styles passed to `pandoc` that then get implemented with `biblatex`. They're not `biblatex` styles.

Comment: @AlanMunn:  yes, exactly.

Comment: @AlanMunn - Many thanks for providing this clarification.

Comment: @user2554330 Can you please add a short, but compilable test document? I do get the note with apa

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz:  That's very interesting.  I have added a simplified example, and it makes me feel that I might not be asking this in the right place.  It's definitely a CSL question, but maybe not a biblatex question after all.

Comment: @user2554330 pandoc does not use biblatex at all. It will hardcode the text of the references at the end of the tex file and not use any bibliography tools at all. You should better aks this at stackoverflow. Latex knowledge won't help you with that.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as this is not a latex problem. Pandoc will hard code the references at the end of the tex file. Changing them will need some intervention at a point before the tex file is created.

Comment: I agree it should be closed.  I'll try SO.  I am advised by the website not to delete it, but I won't object if those of you who can vote to close do so.

Answer (score 1):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

I don't think it's correct to claim that the `note` field is "unusual".

If I load `biblatex` with no options at all, I get a formatted bib entry that's close to what the OP says they desire *and* includes the contents of the `note` field.

[image]

I suppose one could add suitable instructions to display the name if the format "Surname, GivenName", to display the publication year immediated after the author field, and to suppress the `URL:` prefix.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@Manual{R-tables,
  title  = {Tables: Formula-Driven Table Generation},
  author = {Duncan Murdoch},
  note   = {R~package version 0.9.21},
  url    = {https://dmurdoch.github.io/tables/},
  year   = {2023},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}
\usepackage{xurl}

\begin{document}
\cite{R-tables}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks.  As my recent edits show, I'm probably not really using biblatex, just an (imperfect) Pandoc emulation of it.

Comment: does your example use a CSL style?  If so, can you tell me which one, and I'll try it out.

Comment: @user2554330 biblatex does not use CSL, it uses biblatex styles.  There is no straightforward mapping in either direction (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69267).  `biblatex`, supports what you want so either the CSL does not support this or `citeproc` does an imperfect implementation of it, but the problem isn't on the TeX end of things.  If you can work with the LaTeX source (pandoc can generate tex) as Mico shows here what you want is very simple (and can possibly be done even better as `biblatex` supports the likes of a `version` key for `@manual`).